# Using fold on Option without having x => x

Tags: scala

Given:

```
val personsOpt:Option[List[Person]] = ???
```

I prefer:

```
persons = personsOpt.fold(List[Person]()){person => person}
```

To this:

```
persons = personsOpt.getOrElse(List[Person]())
```

For type safety reasons. For example this does not compile:

```
persons = personsOpt.fold(Nil){person => person}
```

Is there a simple way to get the type safety but not have `{person => person}`?

EDIT: Two things now concretely understood:

1. There is nothing un-type-safe about `getOrElse`. For instance this does not compile: `personsOpt.getOrElse("")`
2. `Nil` is `List()` and if its type can't be inferred the compiler will ask you to be explicit. So there can be no type issues with using `Nil`

I couldn't find the link just now, but I did (incorrectly) read that `getOrElse` was somehow less type safe than using `fold` with an `Option`.

Comment: `getOrElse` is exactly the right thing to use in these cases, and there's no difference in type safety.

Comment: Note your `fold` example only fails to compile because `fold` can return any type and type inference is expecting `Nil.type` rather than the `List[Person]` type you want. You can explicitly type `Nil` as `List[Person]`: `personsOpt.fold(Nil : List[Person]){person => person}`

Comment: Wow! (for the minuses). I think it would be fair enough to strike me down if I answered a question using false underlying assumptions. But this was a question.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Agreed—I think the downvotes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the function `identity` which is defined in `Predef`:

```
persons = personsOpt.fold(List[Person]())(identity)
```

I find this however a lot less readable than using `getOrElse`, and using this does not make your code more type-safe than using `getOrElse`. Note that passing `Nil` to `getOrElse` will make it return the correct type:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String)

scala> val personsOpt:Option[List[Person]] = None
personsOpt: Option[List[Person]] = None

scala> val persons = personsOpt.getOrElse(Nil)
persons: List[Person] = List()
```

Note that `persons` is a `List[Person]`.